# visual c++ 2005 x64?

Tags: c++, 64-bit

Could somebody please point me at the download link for Visual C++ 2005 Express x64 (AKA Visual Studio 8) before I am sectioned under the mental health act?

If I want any GCC point release from the last 10 years I can get it in under 30 seconds from a single page. Microsoft's website is a nightmare beyond imagining. Even Google can't get me what I'm looking for. Hours of my life have now disappeared. Please don't post a link to an article from Microsoft about this because I have read them all. I've been through pages which link to other pages, which then loop back on themselves, or point to dead links, or purport to offer a download but which actually link back to marketing material and stock photographs of people laughing at computer screens.

Thanks

Comment: When dealing with Windows development, if you see smiling people you are almost always in the wrong section. I ended up on the Sharepoint marketing blurb-page once and I almost shot myself. Usually you want to keep on MSDN as much as possible to avoid self-injury.

Comment: I need the 5+ year old compiler (no IDE) because I have to build a plug-in/DLL for a 3+ year old application which mandates that particular version of the compiler. Newer versions aren't an option, ABI incompatibility, different conflicting dependencies, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the last one here [Microsoft Windows SDK Update for Windows Vista and .NET Framework 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ff851942).

That will give you Visual C++ 2005 SP1.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a separate package for installing Visual C++ 2005 Express Edition -- or any of the Visual Studio 2005 products -- on x64.

In order to target x64 in VS2005, I'm sorry to say, I'm going to give you this link: [How to: Configure Visual C++ Projects to Target 64-Bit Platforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the 64-bit compiler (no IDE) then you can download it as part of the Windows Vista SDK.

Comment: I'm unlikely to ever find the download link for the particular version of that package I require either.

Comment: Looks like Skurmedel looked it up for you.

Comment: Yes luckily he did because there's nothing in the title or brief description that gives it away as being the thing I'm looking for. I don't have Windows "Server" or "Vista". Why Microsoft can't put the 32 and 64 bit compilers in the same package with a name that reflects the contents of that package, and in a place where I can easily find it I'll never know.

Comment: @mr grumpy - The **do** have complete packages with everything included. It is just called "Professional Edition" so they can charge some money for it. :-)  The free versions are obviously missing some parts.